# Blank page when running HTML page with JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I was following a tutorial on Lynda, when they first introduce us to JSX they use the following example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
        <title>My First React File</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='react-container'></div>
        <script>
            ReactDOM.render(<ul>
                    <li>item 1</li>
                    <li>item 2</li>
                    <li>item 3</li>
                </ul>,
                document.getElementById('react-container'))
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

But this doesn't seem to be working for me. When I run the HTML file in the browser containing the code above, it gives me a blank page.

Could someone please point me to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html), you need to:

- Tell the browser that the JSX is not JavaScript
- Transpile the JSX to JavaScript

So add to the head:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
```

And change your JSX script tag to:

```
<script type="text/babel">
```